# Django - BaseSerializer.is_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

I am creating a base viewset class and trying to use it in two classes.
The viewset has a create method which uses the get_serializer_class() to get the serialzer and creates the object.
But the is_valid() throws error

> TypeError: BaseSerializer.is_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Here is the base class:

```
class BaseViewSet(BaseFilterViewSet):

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    
    def create(self, request: Request, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Response:
        context = super(BaseViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"request": request})
    
        # serializer = super(BaseViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()
        serializer = self.get_serializer_class()
        serializer(data=request.data, context=context)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save(created_by=request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Here is the child class which uses this viewset and defines a get_serializer_class method.

```
class ChildViewSet(BaseViewSet):

    queryset = Child.objects.all().select_related("model2")

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_serializer_class(self) -> Type[BaseSerializer[_MT_co]]:
        if self.action == "stock":
            return StockSerializer
        else:
            return ChildSerializer
```

Many thanks for inputs and help.

Comment: `serializer = serializer(data=request.data, context=context)`

Comment: you should be calling self.get_serializer(request.data) instead of self.get_serializer_class()

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem many thanks. I spent considerable time on it and couldn't see it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`.get_serializer(…)`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself): this will automatically create the serializer with the serializer class that is specified in the [**`.get_serializer_class()`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself) with the context retrieved by the [**`.get_serializer_context(…)`** method call <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself) that already contains the request (as well as the `view` and the `format`). You thus can implement this as:

```
class BaseViewSet(BaseFilterViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    
    def create(self, request: Request, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Response:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save(created_by=request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
```